# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Vue Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I got a problem here when I push the form and I check on Firebase I see that the data is pushed but the data is empty.

I imported the firebase config file to my ProfileInfo.vue file.

```
import { db } from '../../config/db';
```

This is my **method** what I use.

```
AddProfile() {
        this.$firebaseRefs.Profile.push({
            firstName: this.profileData.firstName,
            lastName: this.profileData.lastName,
            phoneNumber: this.profileData.phoneNumber,
            adress: this.profileData.adress,
            gender: this.profileData.gender,
            personalEmail: this.profileData.personalEmail,
            companyName: this.profileData.companyName,
            chamberOfCommerceNumber: this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber,
            street: this.profileData.street,
            houseNumber: this.profileData.houseNumber,
            zipCode: this.profileData.zipCode,
            location: this.profileData.location,
            companyEmail: this.profileData.companyEmail
        })
        this.profileData.firstName = '';
        this.profileData.lastName = '';
        this.profileData.phoneNumber = '';
        this.profileData.adress = '';
        this.profileData.gender = '';
        this.profileData.personalEmail = '';
        this.profileData.companyName = '';
        this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber = '';
        this.profileData.street = '';
        this.profileData.houseNumber = '';
        this.profileData.zipCode = '';
        this.profileData.location = '';
        this.profileData.companyEmail = '';
        // this.$router.push('/internship')
        console.log('Added to database');
    }
```

**Now the data is empty from my Firebare:**

[image]

Comment: The error message suggests that `this.$firebaseRefs.Profile` is undefined.

Comment: I dont sure where you create $firebaseRefs object reference. Have you find out for that?

Comment: I fix it I change the Profile to profile. But now when I go to my Firebase all the data is empty.

Comment: I think you need to use set() : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: @SlimCoder no it doesn't work.